# Autoit script will run but nothing else

Tags: autoit

The script isn't full completed yet, for instance after you type in a input like a teleport, other than teleporting it doesn't do anything, I just never got around to adding anything because the script its self wouldn't run to confirm what I had worked

So my issues-

1. The code will run without showing any errors but won't do anything it's supposed to. it usually ends the script within 10 seconds of starting it.
2. It's supposed to change the direction of the screen however it just outputs the text "north, south, east or west" depending on the random number.

What it is supposed to do is

1. allow the user to input the ore they wish to mine. Then an input for where you wish to do this.
2. Go to that location by "Loadstones"
3. pixel search for the ore that you chose and left click the location that it finds the color

   AND NOW THE PART YOU'VE ALL BEEN WAITING FOR.... THE ACTUAL SCRIPT!

; ore code

```
Global $clay = "clay"
PixelSearch(330, 161, 808, 614,0xCCB481, 0, 0x000000000013019E)
Global $copper = "copper"
PixelSearch(330, 161, 808, 614, 0xF58C4C, 0, 0x00000000004D024A)
Global $tin = "tin"
$tin = PixelSearch(330, 161, 808, 614, 0x8A7F7F, 0, 0x00000000004D024A)
Global $iron = "iron"
PixelSearch(330, 161, 808, 614, 0x744230, 0, 0x00000000004D024A)
Global $coal = "coal"
PixelSearch(330, 161, 808, 614, 0x1F1F1D, 0, 0x00000000004D024A)
Global $mithril = "mithril"
PixelSearch(330, 161, 808, 614, 0x66679F, 0, 0x00000000004D024A)
Global $adamantite = "adamantite"
PixelSearch(330, 161, 808, 614, 0x628164, 0, 0x00000000004D024A)
Global $rune = "rune"
PixelSearch(330, 161, 808, 614, 0x74B1BA, 0, 0x000000000013019E)

;teleports
Global $fallador = "fally"
Global $lumbridge = "lumby"
Global $traverly = "trav"
Global $alkharid = "alkh"
Global $portsarim = "port"
Global $draynor
Global $varrock

HotKeySet("ESC", "Terminate")



Func Terminate()
    Exit 1
EndFunc


Func teleports()
    If $fallador Then
        MouseClick("left", 24, 386, 1, 10) ; click loadstone
        Sleep(2000)
        MouseClick("left", 697, 404, 1, 10) ; click location
        sleep(15000)

    ElseIf $lumbridge Then
        MouseClick("left", 24, 386, 1, 10)
        Sleep(2000)
        MouseClick("Left", 746, 459, 1, 10)
        Sleep(20000)

    ElseIf $traverly Then
        MouseClick("left", 24, 386, 1, 10)
        Sleep(2000)
        MouseClick("left", 666, 385, 1, 10)
        Sleep(20000)

    ElseIf $alkharid Then
        MouseClick("left", 24, 386, 1, 10)
        Sleep(2000)
        MouseClick("left", 785, 452, 1, 10)
        sleep(20000)

    ElseIf $portsarim Then
        MouseClick("left", 24, 386, 1, 10)
        Sleep(2000)
        MouseClick("left", 696, 447, 1, 10)
        Sleep(18000)


    ElseIf $draynor Then
        MouseClick("left", 24, 386, 1, 10)
        Sleep(2000)
        MouseClick("Left", 732, 422, 1, 10)
        Sleep(19000)

    ElseIf $varrock Then
        MouseClick("left", 24, 386, 1, 10)
        Sleep(2000)
        MouseClick("left", 769, 390, 1, 10)
        sleep(17000)

        EndIf
    EndFunc

Func Mine() ; the actual mining function
    InputBox("Select ore", "please enter what you want to mine")       ; input box so user can decide what they want to mine
    InputBox("LOADSTONES REQUIRED!!!", "Please enter the Location you wish to mine")               ; input box that will teleport you
    If $clay Then
        MouseClick("left", 703, 554, 1, 25)
    ElseIf $copper Then
        MouseClick("left",676, 343 , 1, 25)
    ElseIf $tin Then
        MouseClick("left", 498, 301, 1, 25)
    ElseIf $iron Then
        MouseClick("left", 585, 426, 1, 15)
    ElseIf $coal Then
        MouseClick("left",683, 229 , 1, 28)
    ElseIf $mithril Then
        MouseClick("left", 508, 280, 1, 18)
    ElseIf $adamantite Then
        MouseClick("left", 449, 414, 1, 19)
    ElseIf $rune Then
        MouseClick("left", 1,1, 1, 28)
    EndIf
    While 1
    if mine() = 1 Then
        sleep(0)
    ElseIf mine() = 0 Then
        mine()
        EndIf
        WEnd

    Random(0, 5000,0) ; random movements throughout the mining bot
    if Random >=2499 Then
        Send("north",0)
    ElseIf Random = 2500 Then
        Send("west",0)
    ElseIf Random <= 2501 Then
        Send("east", 0)
    ElseIf Random = 5000 Then
        Send("south",0)
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

which would be here but I didn't have the patience nor care to figure out what the popup was saying about changing it so here is a link to codepad for the script.  **( AUTOIT with SciTE compiler)**

http://codepad.org/fjfqxook

Comment: if You dont have the patience or care to figure out what the popup was saying , i am not sure what makes you think people out here will have the patience to read through your so many lines of code and find out why it isn't working

Comment: maybe i phrased it wrong. I didn't feel like spending more time than actually needed to figure out what in the code isn't set up to how the site wants it;  to be able to post it here when I could just as simply post the link; 114 or so lines isn't a lot. This is probably my fault on phrasing, I've been trying to solve this issue for several weeks and am ready to figure it out so taking however long to go through the script just to adjust it for the site seems like a useless step. . .

Comment: Ah runescape. Those were the good old days. Your code will run and the exit because there is nothing left to run. This is a very common mistake, and is solved by adding an infinite while loop while you wait for events after the HotkeySet call.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one infinite loop as below in your script.

```
While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how an infinite loop is going to help you, yet. You need to add more logic.

Maybe you just need to check out some more sweet macro code.

Here's a roll-your-own macro that I made for another game:

> http://codepad.org/TG8zFMKV

It has an example of message input that might come in handy. It also has the ability to pause, show status text, check for exact pixel colors, etc.

*I think people who build macros, like yourself, are some of the smartest people out there.*